# How to speed up the starting time of TestNG tests in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng

I have run into the same problems as others with the dreaded 57% limit. I see this as a bug in eclipse since the startup time for a test is about 5-7 minutes. During this time eclipse hangs on the 57% limit. The problem is that running the same test with another vm argument take exactly the same time as the first time the test was run. This is why I suspect some obscure bug. The solution I am looking for is some workaround in eclipse for this bug. Due to limitaitons I cannot move settings.xml, I cannot move the pom file to a local destination, I cannot uplift TestNG version, ...

So basically I am stuck with what I have. Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Get a better IDE - IntelliJ.

Comment: @duffymo I normally use IntelliJ, but the setup time is a bit longer and I have to test something in a special environment. And yes, I get a lot less angry when working with IntelliJ.

Comment: I have no idea what this 57% limit is, or the Eclipse bug, or anything else you're alluding to.  I wonder if others will be equally confused?  I think it's your tests, not the IDE.   I'd look at those more carefully.  I found that dependency injection for each and every test was killing me until I eliminated it.

Comment: @duffymo this could actually be the problem. However, we base a lot of stuff on spring beans, so I doubt we can get rid of it. Regarding eclipse hanging on 57% you will get a lot of posts on google. The problem is that these posts suggests changes in the setup and this is not possible.

Comment: I did.  I love Spring, but it was killing my tests.  The problem is that you instantiate an initialize the Spring bean factory for every test.  If you add it to a static block in a base class you'll only initialize once.  A better thing is to inject yourself and use mocks.

Comment: You may actually have found the problem. Unfortunately this is a design decison so I have a limited power to do anything. Thank you for the answers (even if they incline that I cannot do much). However Intellij seems to be able to handle this better (so probably I do only have to suffer for a short time).

Comment: Let me guess - a "designer" who doesn't write code said you have to do it his/her way.  (sigh)   You can push back as much as you'd like.  I can tell you that manual injection is the solution.  IntelliJ won't make it better.  It's a feature of the unit testing frameworks JUnit and TestNG, not the IDE.  Do some research to see if there's a better way to initialize the bean factory just once.  That's the key.

Comment: So the culprits are your tests and you are trying to cover the issue by using a different IDE? Does that make sense? From my point of view not. Fix the real issue....it will not become better over the time...and a start up time for a test of such amount of time makes a unit tests in my eyes useless cause it takes too much time...so devs will later ignore it cause it is too much effort to just wait for a test...Have you checked to run your test on console via Maven...does the tests takes also such long time?

Comment: @khmarbaise this is not exactly true. I use IntelliJ since Eclipse makes me wanna smash things. The build time is one of the minor issues compared to terrible maven integration and more. Anyway as stated, it is not within my power to take the decision about how to handle the "real issue". Changing this is a design decision and I am not a part of that group. Also, it is not unit tests in normal sense. What I am working on is actually a test framework, which is based on TestNG. This is our product and the normal unit test (for our product) is much faster.